# HttpPost file from a directory

Tags: asp.net-core, io, httpclient

I have an image file in my projects directory, I need to Post it to another api but no success so far.
I have tried to mock IFormFile but it seems like its empty or something.

any ideas?

here is the extension I found and used but it doesn't seem to work.

```
public static IFormFile AsMockIFormFile(this FileInfo physicalFile)
    {
        var fileMock = new Mock<IFormFile>();
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
        writer.Write(physicalFile.OpenRead());
        writer.Flush();
        ms.Position = 0;
        var fileName = physicalFile.Name;
        //Setup mock file using info from physical file
        fileMock.Setup(_ => _.FileName).Returns(fileName);
        fileMock.Setup(_ => _.Length).Returns(ms.Length);
        fileMock.Setup(m => m.OpenReadStream()).Returns(ms);
        fileMock.Setup(m => m.ContentDisposition).Returns(string.Format("inline; filename={0}", fileName));
        //...setup other members (code removed for brevity)


        return fileMock.Object;
    }
```

then when I try to copy this image to the folder to see if its actualy an image the image is 0 bytes:

```
  var stream = System.IO.File.Create(@"wwwroot\images\dsadas.jpeg");
            
                await fileMock.Object.CopyToAsync(stream);
```

if there is another way, or a way to make this work I would appreciate it!

Comment: Do you have to mock this file? Can you use other clients such as postman to send a file?

Comment: I am mocking this file to do it from my application